# Where am I doing wrong for inserting node to a binary tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I do research in stackoverflow and can not find out where am i doing wrong. Codes that I found are similiar to mine. I have difficulties on coding AddNodeToTree function. When I run this code its output always first item of the tree. I want to code it Iteratively. Could you help me what am I missing? Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Node{

    int data;
    struct _Node* left;
    struct _Node* right;
}Node;


void* AllocateMemory(size_t size){

    void* pvMem;

    pvMem=malloc(size);

    if(pvMem==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot Allocate Memory!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return pvMem;

}

Node* NewNode(int data){

    Node* new_node;

    new_node = AllocateMemory(sizeof(Node));

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

Node* AddNodeToTreeRecursive(Node* root, int data){

    if(NULL==root)
        return (NewNode(data));

    if(root->data > data)
        root->left = AddNodeToTreeRecursive(root->left, data);
    else if(root->data < data)
        root->right = AddNodeToTreeRecursive(root->right, data);

    return root;

}

void PrintList(Node* root){

    if(root==NULL)
        return;

printf("DATA: %d\n", root->data);

    PrintList(root->left);

    PrintList(root->right);


}


Node* AddNodeToTree(Node* root, int data){

    Node* new_item = NewNode(data);
    Node** temp = &root;

    if(root==NULL)
        return new_item;

    while(*temp!=NULL){

        if((*temp)->data > data)
            temp = &(*temp)->left;

        else if((*temp)->data <= data)
            temp = &(*temp)->right;

    }

    *temp = new_item;


    return root;
}


int main()
{

    Node* root=NULL;

    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 30);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 20);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 10);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 1);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 5);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 3);
    root=AddNodeToTree(root, 7);

    PrintList(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at `AddNodeToTree` : `temp = new_item;` is no effect. `while(temp!=NULL){...}` == `temp = NULL;`

Comment: I dont understand your point. When "while" is completed then temp must be a right place to insert new_item. Could you explain more thanks.

Comment: @user2987298 When the while loop terminates, `temp` is `NULL`. You are not inserting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp = new_item;` doesn't do what you think it does. All it does is to reassign the *local* variable `temp` to something else. It doesn't change the pointer you copied it from.

Think of `Node` as a person and each hand of that person (which can point to another person) being the `left` and `right` pointers respectively. Now your tree is a whole network of people pointing to each other. Then `temp` is someone else' hand, repeatedly pointing to different people, until he/she ends up pointing at nothing. Then you tell him/her to point to someone else (`new_item`), which obviously won't change your network of people pointing at each other, since `temp` isn't part of this network.

The simplest fix I can think of is to make `temp` a `Node**`:

```
Node** temp = &root;

// your code to traverse the tree, except that you should
// replace `temp = ...` with `temp = &...`
//   and every other occurrence of `temp` with `*temp`

*temp = new_item;
```

To extend the metaphor, `temp` would then be pointing to a hand rather than a person, and changing `*temp` would involve making that hand point to another person. Since that hand is part of the network, changing it would change the network.

Comment: request for member 'left' in something but not a structure or union

Comment: Since `temp` is now a `Node**`, you'll need to change every place you use it. Replace `temp = ...` with `temp = &...` and every other occurrence of `temp` with `*temp`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fishy in AddNodeToTree

```
while(temp!=NULL){

    if(temp->data > data)
        temp = temp->left;

    else if(temp->data <= data)
        temp = temp->right;

}
```

The reason is: temp the root. You passed it in as a pointer.

You are setting it to be the left or right node.

You are returning root, but you modified it by modifying temp.